# Verify certificate in android by boost failed

Tags: android, android-ndk, ssl-certificate, boost-asio, boost-beast

I know that default path of certificates in android(maybe many devices) is `/system/etc/security/cacerts` , When I check the folder's contents I found that has ***.0** files (too many files).

1- boost can detect this folder by default? ([*set_default_verify_paths*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_default_verify_paths.html)) or I should *add_verify_path* this folder?

2- I used explicit path (by adding path that has mentioned in question 1) , but it give me error(exception):

**`handshake: certificate verify failed`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the problem was in low level of codes ...

Methods on file name hashing was different in android vs openssl!